# Are Lambda Captured Variables Guarenteed To Survive Entire life of Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, closures

In Java values of captured lambda variables can be used beyond the scope of the original variable, as follows:

```
interface MyInterface{
    void doSomething(  );
}

class Example {
 MyInterface lambda;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Example e = new Example();
     e.f1();
     e.f2();
 }
 void f1() {
     int local = 777;
     lambda = () -> System.out.println(local);
 }
 void f2() {
     lambda.doSomething(); // prints 777
 }
}
```

Anonymous classes can do this as well. I suspect implementations would do this by capturing the local values by copy.

Are the captured locals guaranteed by the specification to survive for as long the lambda does?

I would love a reference to the relevant passage in the docs. ( I searched, didn't find it )

Comment: I get it now. Have you looked at the compiled code? That will probably tell you something.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OK. With my poor command of bytecode it certainly looks like a copy of 777 is loaded into the stack of the returned object in f1. But this may be just an implementation detail. I was looking for something more formal.

Comment: "*Are the captured locals guaranteed by the specification to survive for as long the lambda does?*" - Yes. I do not know the exact JLS paragraph outlining it, but this is, at least in parts, why variables accessed in a lambda must be `final` or effectively `final`.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect implementations would do this by capturing the local values by copy.

Correct. Because this would be incredibly confusing if the captured local is modified, `javac` will simply refuse to compile your code unless the captured variable is either [A] marked `final` or [B] 'effectively final', which is in the spec, and which means: You could mark it final.

This copy survives for as long as is needed. In general the docs give you the guarantee that you can't get core dumps in java unless you involve JNI, and the garbage collection specs don't go a heck of a lot further than that.

Answer (score 1):

In [6.5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1), it is said that (emphasis mine)

> If the declaration declares a final variable which is definitely assigned before the simple expression, the meaning of the name is the ***value*** of that variable. Otherwise, the meaning of the expression name is the variable declared by the declaration.

Therefore, `local` in your lambda *means* 777, the (final) value you assigned to `local`. And this is implemented by making a copy of the variable as you have suspected correctly. Whether or not the local variable "survives" doesn't really matter here.

According to another section, the local variable doesn't "survive" ([4.12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3)):

> A local variable ceases to exist when its declaration is no longer in scope.

When you run the lambda in `f2`, the local variable's declaration is out of scope, so it "ceases to exist".